# What is the difference between 1."compared with" and "compared to" 2.'Match up with' and 'Match up to'?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning, vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

What is the difference between...

> "compared with" and "compared to" 
>  Match up with' and 'Match up to'

Comment: For "compare with" and "compare to" see this thread - http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20254/compare-with-vs-compare-to

Answer (score 1):

When we talk about the way in which two or more things are different, we use "compared to" or "compared with":

> Your flat is quite big compared to/with ours.

We use "match up to/with" (usually in a negative sense) as an intransitive verb meaning to be as good as someone or something. For example:

> His performance did not match up to/with our expectations.

We also use "match up with" to mean to be the same. For example:

> His account of the event did not match up with yours.

We also use "match up with" to mean to set or hold people or things in competition. For example:

> Our team is matched up with a world class team.