# Should 'in contrast' always be followed by 'to'?

Tags: prepositions

Is 'in contrast' always followed by the preposition 'to', or are there situations where it can correctly be followed by 'with' or a different preposition?

Comment: I could see myself saying "Note that the red plumage of the robin (a bird) is in stark contrast with its bleak surroundings."

Comment: This is not quite your example though as I added stark so it breaks the phrase.  Perhaps: "Figure A is big.  In contrast, Figure B is small."  Though the 'to' here is implied and I haven't added a proposition at all.  I would also pronounce 'contrast' different here putting the emphasis on the first syllable instead of the second.  Good question as I cannot think of another use.

Comment: I'd say that you can use it at the start of a sentence to mark the difference of the subsequent object / event from the preceding one, i.e.

"This pill is red. In contrast, this one is blue."

Comment: Thank you.  I think that in both of the examples where 'in contrast' starts a sentence, I would also use 'by', as in "Figure A is big.  By contrast, Figure B is small."  The more I think about this the less I know what sounds right!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use either ***in contrast to*** or ***in contrast with***.

Without considering ***[by/in contrast](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/by-in-contrast)*** (i.e., when there is no preposition after *by/in contrast*, as suggested in the comments above), both ***in contrast to*** and ***in contrast with*** are equally valid.

From *Garner's Modern American Usage*:

> **in contrast with; in contrast to.** These are equally good. **See contrast (A).**
>
> **contrast. A. Prepositions with.** One *contrasts* something *with*—not *to*—something else. But it’s permissible to write either *in contrast to* or *in contrast with*. Cf. **compare with.**

(You can find a quote by Bryan Garner, the author of *Garner's Modern American Usage* in *The Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style*, which was quoted on this site under ["compare with" or "compare to"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/20259/3281).)