# "Compared with" vs "Compared to"

Tags: adjectives

Which one is correct

> Compared to another countries
>
> Compared with another countries

Comment: There are a lot of questions with queries about the usage of '_to and with_'. Try [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=to+and+with) search result.

Comment: [This](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/20254/29795) and [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/583/165334) might be useful.

Comment: "another countries" is always ungrammatical, because "another" is just "an + "other", so it's always singular. "Other" by itself would work, though.