# can't compare to vs. can't compare with

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Example sentence:

> You can't compare a few hours *to/with* many years.

Based on [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20254/compare-with-or-compare-to), I think you can use either? Or maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that both of

> - You can't compare a few hours to many years.
> - You can't compare a few hours with many years.

are grammatical and natural, and that there is no significant difference of meaning between them. They can be used interchangeably. The differences suggested in the linked thread are in my view not meaningful, and the authorities cited to support those differences do not agree with one another.